# URL in Firefox 4 gets focus instead of Google Search

Tags: firefox

I have Google set as my homepage and load it when I open a new tab.

Where in Firefox 3 the cursor would be inside the Google Search field so I could start typing my query, it now sits at the end of the URL.

Example: I want to look for "brown foxes." Instead of searching for "brown foxes" on an enter, as it used to be, I now go to google.com/brown foxes and get the Google 404 error.

Is there any way to force the focus back to the search box as it used to be?

Comment: What setting do you use to open Google in each new tab?  Normally I use about:blank for homepage, but in trying to reproduce your problem I changed it to Google.com.  However, I still have a blank window when I open a tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact solution, but here are two better use-cases for you:

1: Use [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/).
This will make your the Firefox AwesomeBar a universal search bar.

2: Use [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/).
This will route all your invalid URLs (eg. google.com/brown foxes) to valid search engine queries; among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Better: use NewTabUrl plugin and untick option "select location bar after loading the new tab"